# Transparent Toolbar in Mac Catalyst

Tags: uiwindow, mac-catalyst

I was able to create a unified toolbar in Mac Catalyst with this in the `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```
// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    // hide the titlebar
    windowScene.titlebar?.toolbar = NSToolbar()
    windowScene.titlebar?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    ...
}
```

But I want to make the toolbar transparent like in this example: 
https://lukakerr.github.io/swift/nswindow-styles#11-transparent-toolbar-without-seperator

Is this even possible in Mac Catalyst?

Comment: It should be possible and existing solutions will also pass the App Store review process since there are already Apps in the Mac App Store. E.g. CARROT Weather.   I am curious to see a simple solution. Don't understand why its not possible right out of the box. Its so essential for a modern looking App.

Comment: Check that link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/optimizing_your_ipad_app_for_mac

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible in Mac Catalyst. In your SceneDelegate.swift file, set both toolbar and title visibility to `false` and `.hidden` respectively.

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    windowScene.titlebar?.toolbar?.isVisible = false
    windowScene.titlebar?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    #endif
}
```

Comment: This thread showed me how to hide the title bar for mac catalyst apps, would have asked a question and got a 500 downvote bomb, so cheers :)

Comment: @Benj, I'm glad you've found this thread helpful! Don't hesitate to ask questions relating to new software, they're always a hassle without proper documentation and the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 3):

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

```
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    
    if let titlebar = self.view.window?.windowScene?.titlebar {
            titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
            titlebar.toolbar = nil
        }
    #endif
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a similar solution:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) //check target
if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
    titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
    titlebar.toolbar = nil
}
#endif

}
```